# Inserting a string id into GET using requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

The API I am working with shows that get requests for status of recorders should look like this:
    `GET /api/v1/Recorders('id')/Status` where I need to insert the string id of the recorder.

I am having trouble finding the correct way to insert the id. I have tried:

```
recId = 123
response = requests.get('https://lecturexxxxx.org/ets/api/v1/Recorders('{0}')/Status',format(recId))
```

but so far unsuccessful using requests in Python. All attempted variations have been unsuccessful thus far.

Comment: Could you list the errors you are receiving, and what variations you have attempted?

Comment: Try this. `response = requests.get("https://lecturexxxxx.org/ets/api/v1/Recorders('{0}')/Status".format(recId))`

Comment: Python 3 also introduced another way of string formatting i.e. f-string, which looks more cleaner than string.format. Check this out https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: Try this. `response = requests.get("https://lecturexxxxx.org/ets/api/v1/Recorders/{}/Status".format(recId))`

Comment: you can't nest single quotes in this way. See sameer's example of nesting instead.

Comment: Yes I see Sameer's example of nesting works :) Many thanks to all of you ! I am also going to use the python 3 string formatting as well..